# Particular Query from Queryset in Django

Tags: python, django, database

I have a model in Django called Accounts which has id, name, email, and balance fields. I want to retrieve the particular dataset when one visits the detail page. Say when I click on the details page I send through a string "name" which contains the name of the user the account is owned by. I am trying to obtain the particular query but to no avail. This is what the Queryset returns on `Accounts.objects.all()` ==> `<QuerySet [<Account: UserA>, <Account: UserB>, <Account: UserC>, <Account: UserD>, <Account: UserE>, <Account: UserF>, <Account: UserG>, <Account: UserH>, <Account: UserI>, <Account: UserJ>]>` 
I have tried `Accounts.objects.values().get(id=id)` but that provides a dictionary of id, user_id, and balance. I want to access the email of the user as well. 
I tried `Accounts.objects.get(username=name)` but it returns the error too many values to unpack.
A way to do is `Accounts.objects.all()[id]` which is cheap and not dynamic since if we delete some users then it wont work.
**user/models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    balance = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user)
```

What am I missing here? or what is going wrong here?

Comment: Please provide `models.py`.

Comment: What does `Accounts.objects.get(username=name)` return? I mean, what error does it cause?

Comment: @bichanna Field 'id' expected a number but got 'UserA'.

Comment: @RevTpark what is parameter do you want to search, id or username from model User?

Comment: @EkiSaputra username

Comment: @RevTpark if your username is unique, you can use this Accounts.objects.get(user__username=name).values('user__email') and get email only

Comment: that did it thanks

Answer (score 0):

if you want particular data and not duplicate data single only, you can use get, but if returned multiple data use filter, example:

get

```
Accounts.objects.get(id=id).values('user__email') #user__ is name your field relational object
```

filter

```
Accounts.objects.filter(user__username=name) # possible duplicate data, not unique
```